# C2011: 'struct' type redefinition and C2027: use of undefined type

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

In a file named `types.h`, I have defined

```
struct entry {
  entry( int a, int t ) : addr(a), time(t) {}
  int addr;
  int time;
};
```

In another file I want to use the struct like this in `compress.h`:

```
#include "types.h"
#include <vector>
class Compress {
public:
  void insert( int a, int t )
  {
    theVec.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) 
       theVec.push_back( entry(a, t) );
  }

private:
  std::vector< entry > theVec;
};
```

In the main file, I wrote

```
#include "compress.h"
int main()
{
  Compress *com = new Compress;
  com->insert(10, 100);
  return 0;
}
```

However at the line of push_back, I get these errors

```
error C2011: 'entry' : 'struct' type redefinition
see declaration of 'entry'
error C2027: use of undefined type 'entry'
see declaration of 'entry'
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: do you have header guards in your header?

Comment: Can you post a [minimal, complete example](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: @Ivaylo Strandjev: I have edited the post and include the headers.

Comment: Does types.h include any other header?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `types.h` file you should have something like this:

```
#ifndef TYPES_H
#define TYPES_H

struct ...

#endif
```

This will prevent the compiler from parsing the include file mulitple times if you include it more than once, which would cause multiple definitions.

The name itself doesn't matter, but you should make sure that it is unique and not defined by some other include file as well.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check the include guard of types.h.

Try to have the file start with the line

```
#pragma once

// your declarations
```

Comment: Yes it is. And yet it offers advantages towards a traditional include guard. Lots of widely spread compilers such as MSVC and GCC understand it fine, it has much less footprint, is more self-describing and is said to offer better performance on large MSVC projects because Visual Studio actually will not touch the file twice, whereas a traditional guard is always evaluated. Resulting in some cases in 10% faster builds. And since the OP uses Visual Studio, that won't do him any harm.

Comment: But "pragma once" might also cause problems - at least on Linux I have seen problems whenever a header is available in 2 locations (eg. via symbolic link or whatever). GCC does not recognize this and includes the header twice then.